# What is win32 project in visual c++?

Tags: c++, winapi, project

While I was creating a console application, I saw the win32 project. I created one and saw a bunch of code (which I supose is for creating the main window).Is this better then visual c++ winform application?If so why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this better then visual c++ winform application?

No, it's different.  "Better" depends on your goals.

A Windows Forms application will be a C++/CLI application, and use .NET.  This may be "easier" for developing a GUI appilcation, but adds a lot of complexity and dependencies.

A Win32 application will not take a dependency on .NET, but then you can't use the .NET types.  For details on what you can make when choosing that option, see [MSDN's Win32 Application documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2zy4kwk%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).